# Receive a Jagged Array in VBA (VB6)

Tags: vb.net, vba, vb6, arrays

I currently have a VB.NET dll that returns a jagged array of double. This is the declaration:

```
Public Function CalcMatching(ByRef dataArray1 As Object, 
    ByRef dataLen1 As Integer, ByRef dataArray2 As Object, 
    ByRef dataLen2 As Integer, ByRef matchingType As String) As Double()()
```

It works well inside VB.NET, but when I insert it into a VBA project, I noticed that after the execution of the function, while retrieving the data, the "Type mismatch' exception is raised inside VBA.

I searched over the internet, but I could not find a declaration of a jagged array inside VBA. is that possible? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: I have probably misunderstood your point, but perhaps dataArray1 as Variant?

Comment: Is this the VB.Net declaration?

Comment: wqw, yes this is the .NET declaration.

Comment: Remou, Variant is not a type available at VB.NET. But it's not generating any problems, the issue is with the return type of the function, that is not accepted by VBA.

Comment: There is no VBA syntax for a strongly typed array of array of double (or anything). To get a jagged array in VBA you use an array of Variants, with elements of the array containing arrays that can be different lengths. (See this for the basics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428811/pass-multidimensional-array-into-excel-udf-in-vba/3430854#3430854) My .NET is pretty rusty, but I suspect it's not possible to do what you want without gymnastics. You'll probably have to return something VBA *will* take, like a 2-D array, or a Collection (of arrays or Collections), and crunch it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess without seeing the calling VBA code, but I believe this is being caused by having ByRef arguments instead of ByVal.  There is stronger type checking when using ByRef arguments which you can read about [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/138535).

Comment: Steve, the parameters are not generating any problems, the issue is with the return type of the function, that is not accepted by VBA.